# Is there a way of specifying the format of input of date.js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datejs

I'm using the Date.js library and jQuery. This is my code:

```
var parsedDate2 = Date.parse(date);
alert(parsedDate2.getTime()/1000);
```

When I use the date:

```
12/11/2015 08:00 PM
```

It treats it as `MM/DD/YYYY ...`

But when I use the date:

```
27/11/2015 08:00 PM
```

Then it treats it as `DD/MM/YYYY ...`, which is actually the version that I prefer. So how can I set up the format `DD/MM/YYYY ...` to use all the time and forget about the `MM/DD/YYYY ...` ?

Comment: https://github.com/datejs/Datejs/blob/master/src/parser.js#L1097 https://github.com/datejs/Datejs/blob/master/src/globalization/en-US.js#L44 Given how old this library is, any reason not to use MomentJS instead?

Comment: Date.js hasn't been updated for 7 years. If it works for you, great. If you find any issues they are unlikely to be fixed so you may need a newer library  like [moment](http://momentjs.com/).

Comment: @Sampson I followed your advice, but when I wrote `var d1 = Date.parseExact(date, "d/m/Y h:i A"); alert(d1)` then I got `null`... What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: @Sampson - the reason is very simple, I don't know exactly how to use moment in my particular case... Also, could you please post it as an answer and not as a comment, so then I can accept it? :)

Comment: @randomuser1 You'll find more people here willing to help you with a modern, supported library, than with an extremely old, unsupported library :) To be honest, I don't know anything about Date.js (I do know, and use moment); I just did a cursory scour of their repo.

Comment: @Sampson okay, I just googled and used moment, it works super fine, so if you suggest me it as an answer I'll accept it for future users :) Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Date.js library you're using is nearly a decade old, and appears to have no recent updates. I would encourage you to instead us something like moment.js, which is thriving and well-supported.

With moment.js, you can [pass the format as the second argument](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/):

```
var date = moment( "12/11/2015", "DD-MM-YYYY" );
```